# Hx711 gives random values with RaspberryPi 4

Tags: gpio, pi-4

I created a weight scale using a RaspberryPi, Hx711 and 4 load cells. I followed [this](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/digital-raspberry-pi-scale-weight-sensor-hx711/) tutorial and did everything like shown there. This is the circuit they used:

[image: The circuit]

I also used [tatobari's hx711py library](https://github.com/tatobari/hx711py).
When I run the `example.py` without making any changes I always get `0.0` printed out, however when I change some things in `example.py` and tare both the A and the B channel and then read values from both A and B channel I get "random" values printed for B channel and again `0.0` for A channel. The values do not change even If I put weight on the sensors.

Here are the outputs I get:

[image: Outputs]

And this is what my circuit looks like:
(The red wires are the diagonals)

[image: Circuit 1]

[image: Circuit 2]

[image: Circuit 3]

[image: Circuit 4]

[image: Circuit 5]

Comment: The photos are too small to be that helpful.  My only experience used one load cell in the centre of the weighing platform.  Have you tried reading individual load cells? I used [hx711](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_HX711_py)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I enlarged the photos, maybe now it's easier to see. Do I just run the Hx711.py file when I download it? Does it require DT and SCK to be connected to specific pins on RaspberryPi? I have DT connected to GPIO 5 and SCK to GPIO 6.

Comment: Could you share your code? Or did you just run the Hx711.py file?

Comment: To test go to line 245 and set the GPIO you are using.  Then run with python HX711.py.  When used in this mode the module does a self test.  Normally I'd expect the module to be imported and the part in the `__main__` section to be replicated in the user script.

Comment: "when I change some things in example.py" - you may want to explain what "some things" are exactly.

Comment: I changed it to read values from B channel because on A channel the value is always zero. Also the values are not stable at all. Do you know why this could be? Do you know what unit are the measurements in? Is it grams or something else?